# Embedding a standalone spring application jar in Spring boot application as single context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a external client Jar file which uses Spring core, uses ClasspathApplicationContext loader to load app-context.xml (also embeded in jar file).
The jar file is invoked using main method, and expects some arguments and runs as a stand alone java application.

I have my primary spring boot based rest application, I need to incorporate this stand alone application in my application and run it under one single context.
I plan to use functionality provided by client jar as a service, from my rest controller.

Any pointers or ideas on how to do this would be great.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar file as a dependency in the new rest application project and add @ImportResource annotation on your Spring boot main class inside your rest application and provide the xml files as classpath resources which needs to be loaded in the context. This creates all the beans defined in the xml contexts which u can autowired to build the functionalities in your new application.